# Restrict access to Heroku app by IP?

Tags: heroku

Does Heroku support an inbound firewall? I'd like to restrict access to my app by IP. I have two sites that need access to it and both have static IP addresses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a configurable firewall (like AWS security groups).

You could write some simple HTTP middleware at an application level however that checks `X-Forwarded-For` (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers) against a whitelist.

IP restrictions aren't a 1:1 replacement for a proper authentication system though.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to @elithrar's answer, currently (as of this writing, 2023) you can achieve a proper authentication using the following solution from [Heroku's official guide for Private Space VPN Connections](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-space-vpn-connection). This can be achieved using VPN Tunneling as explained in [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-space-vpn-connection),

> Heroku Private Spaces and Shield Spaces can configure a connection to another private network using IPSec VPN. This lets dynos connect to hosts on your private networks and vice versa. Connections are established over the public Internet, but all traffic is encrypted using IPSec.

> Currently, only one VPN connection (with two redundant tunnels) is supported per Private Space.